# Angular2: How to import rx-dom

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I want to use DOM in angular project like this

```
Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest
```

but DOM is not available on Rx which Im importing like this

```
import Rx = require('rxjs');
```

I also tried to import rxjs dom but error was can not find module, I installed rxjs-dom like this

```
npm install rx-lite-dom
```

but Im unable to import it so that I can DOM on Rx object

Comment: This comment is for people who want to install `Rx.DOM` for doing things like `Rx.DOM.focus('#myInput')`. Binding to dom events basically. But **this is not the way**. The way to do this in angular 2.0 is using `Observable.formEvent('#myInput' 'focus')`. I lost half a day trying to install `rx-dom` when was this better solution. As for jsonpRequest you can use [this library](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp). then do: `Observable.formPromise(your_jsonp_promise)` which should work because `fetchJsonp` returns a promise. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the Rx variable, you can import it into an Angular project using:

```
import * as Rx from 'rx-dom';
```

You will then have access to the Rx variable, including the jsonpRequest as in:

```
Rx.DOM.jsonpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJS author here, `rx-dom` is an RxJS version 4 library related to `rx`... `rxjs` is version 5 and up.

For anyone that comes across this question, the answer is to just use any old JSONP library (or whatever) and convert it to an observable using `defer`, `from`, or just wrap what you'd normally do with it using `new Observable()`.